# Launch an application on button click from a web page

Tags: java, web-applications, applet

In my web application I need to launch a Windows application installed on client machine when a button in the page is clicked.

I know there are security policies in browsers that avoid this by default, but I also know application that do this. An example could be online meeting, web conferencing applications like WebEx or GoToMeeting.

How they do that?

I'm working with Java, so I'm wondering if Java Applets are an option to achieve this.

Is there some other well known way to solve this issue?

**NOTE** application execution MUST be allowed by user

Comment: My personal opinion: Java applets are "dead"; for example chrome has dropped Java support completely. The only situation where applets are still an option would be very controlled environments - where you control OS and browsers versions to guarantee that your applets dont stop working just because somebody hit some "update" button.

Comment: @EddyG I've never worked with applets but, as you suggest, I know they are an almost dead technology. I've mentioned it because I need a way to access to client OS.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it with applet. but user must allow to run it. it is hard to run some extern application from button or link because this is potentially danger behaviour. Remember the applet can not get access to the files on user computer and other servers (unless it is digitally signed)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

And [forget applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).  Soon Chrome won't be able to load them (along with a number of other plug-ins) at all.